# Google Data Studio Bar graph - same name appears as separate on Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

My Data Studio is connected to Google Sheet.

The name "Private" appears as 2 separate bar charts when the name is the same. How do I ensure that the data is consolidated under one name "Private"

Image of bar chart

[image: Image of bar chart]

Answer (score 0):

As a guess there might be some additional whitespace in the *Private* words. If that's the case you have two options:

- Make sure there is no whitespace in the original data in google sheets
- Write a custom field in data studio using the TRIM function to clear any whitespace

Comment: No worries! Any chance you can approve my answer if you're happy with it?